# Apollo Client not sending JWT bearer token in Nextjs Lamda

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, next.js, apollo-client

## TLDR

The header `authorization` is not being sent with apollo. This leads to `You do not have the appropriate capabilities to perform this action`

```
const apolloClient = ({ cookies: { token = null }, headers }) => {
  const authLink = setContext(_ => {
    console.info(token) //correct tokens
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    }
  })

  return new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([
      onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
          console.error(graphQLErrors, networkError)
      }),
      authLink.concat(
        createHttpLink({
          uri: graphQL,
          credentials: 'same-origin',
          fetch: fetch,
        })
      ),
    ]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  })
}
```

### Long Version

I have need to authenticate myself in one of my `nextjs lamba` files which now lives inside `/pages/api/*`

I currently have a `apollo.serverless.js` file, this is imported into `pages/api/users/update/role/[userId].js` where I do my db interactions.

This is where it gets a little messy for me. I am not certain this is the only way to do it, but it is where my brain took me. I am passing the `req 
into`apollo.serverless.js` so that I have access to the bearer token that is inside the cookies.

It may be as simple as having my setup incorrect for my apollo.client.

I am testing the link directly `http://localhost:3000/api/users/update/role/dXNlcjoxMTg=` as the stripe webhook will access this url directly with a query param.

## pages/api/users/update/role/[userId].js

```js
import { useQuery, useMutation } from '../../../../../lib/apollo/apollo.serverless'
import { updateMemberRole, allUsers } from '../../../queries/users'

export default async (req, res) => {
  let data
  try {
    const mutationInfo = await useMutation(
      {
        mutation: updateMemberRole,
        variables: {
          userId: req.query.userId,
        },
      },
      req
    )
    data = mutationInfo.data
  } catch (err) {
    data = err
  }
  res.status(200).json({ data })
}
```

## Headers sent with [userId]

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: analyticsCookieAccepted=1; analyticsCookieNoticeClosed=1; _ga=GA1.1.2044509544.1574855120; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; OPTOUTMULTI=0:0%7Cc4:0%7Cc3:0%7Cc2:0; wp-settings-45=editor%3Dhtml%26libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26imgsize%3Dfull; wp-settings-time-45=1575018303; theme=light; wp-settings-time-1=1575496501; utag_main=v_id:016eacdb7ad1001fa3af49cf1fec01069001606100fb8$_sn:18$_se:1$_ss:1$_st:1575891251585$ses_id:1575889451585%3Bexp-session$_pn:1%3Bexp-session; wordpress_logged_in_86a9106ae65537651a8e456835b316ab=glasshousegames%7C1578351721%7CtL4KMHIW7tTAUuCzUOJd8r6Mu5buST9mheH2tn9WFQs%7C593e133b11f6c0745f577e32d66db0cf1ccfa012504f9015fc64c515d2df77d2; token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzgwNTgyOTIsIm5iZiI6MTU3ODA1ODI5MiwiZXhwIjoxNTc4NjYzMDkyLCJkYXRhIjp7InVzZXIiOnsiaWQiOiIxMTgifX19.iMSh4KjuON3otpOqO3TXpYAh2bQYu48sqm9pzsgeBis
Host: localhost:3002
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36
```

## apollo.serverless.js

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { fetch } from 'cross-fetch/polyfill'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error'
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link'
import { graphQL } from 'app.config'
import ApolloClass, { sortParams } from '~/lib/apollo/apollo.class'

dotenv.config()

const apolloClient = ({ cookies: { token = null }, headers }) => {
  const authLink = setContext(_ => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    }
  })

  return new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([
      onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
        if (graphQLErrors)
          graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) => console.log(`[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`))
        if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`)
      }),
      authLink.concat(
        createHttpLink({
          uri: graphQL,
          credentials: 'same-origin',
          fetch: fetch,
        })
      ),
    ]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  })
}

export const useQuery = async function(query) {
  const { options = {} } = sortParams([...arguments])
  const { loading, data: queryData, error, ...props } = await apolloClient.query({
    query,
    ...options,
  })
  let transformData = {}

  if (queryData) transformData = new ApolloClass(queryData).start()
  return {
    queryData,
    error,
    loading,
    data: transformData,
  }
}

export const useMutation = async function(mutation, req) {
  const { data } = await apolloClient(req).mutate(mutation)
  return { data }
}
```

## Error

```
// 20200106132714
// http://localhost:3002/api/users/update/role/dXNlcjoxMTg=

{
  "data": {
    "graphQLErrors": [
      {
        "message": "You do not have the appropriate capabilities to perform this action",
        "category": "user",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 2,
            "column": 3
          }
        ],
        "path": [
          "updateUser"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "networkError": null,
    "message": "GraphQL error: You do not have the appropriate capabilities to perform this action"
  }
}
```

So I believe the problem is that my headers are not being sent, as I cannot see them in the headers detailed here , I can not see them in my headers when looking `http://localhost:3000/api/users/update/role/cm9sZTpzdGFuZGFyZA==`

It is worth mentioning I am using GraphQL and [wp-GraphQL](https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql) with JWT as my auth token. And handling the JWT tokens with[JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/). The reason I am not drawing more attention to this is that I cannot see any `Bearer SomeToken` in my headers, so I am sure once the token is sent over everything work. JWT is correctly working in all my interactions from the cookie.

## .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.)
RewriteRule ^(.) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

<ifmodule mod_headers.c="">
    # SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.domain\.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(localhost|now.sh|dev.domain1.games)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Content-Disposition"
</ifmodule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I think you should make sure Authentication header sent

Comment: Ye, this is the problem I am having. But I cannot get it sent no matter what I try. So help there would be great

Comment: is the cookie "httpOnly" ?

Comment: Interesting idea. I will certainly check this, though I am testing locally and it works with normal requests. Just not inside the lamba. But I will confirm where cookie is avialble. But I have confirmed that I have access to the token from the cookies. But the problem is, it seems, that I cannot set custom headers.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your .htaccess file

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

Comment: Thank you saf. I already have this in my file. ```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.)
RewriteRule ^(.) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1```

Comment: I think its better to run fetch call using javascript from your browser to your server providing the headers required.
At your server side check if the header received properly.
This just to identify whether the missing headers are from your client or server side

Comment: I am actually using `fetch` inside apollo-client.       `authLink.concat(
        createHttpLink({
          uri: graphQL,
          credentials: 'same-origin',
          fetch: fetch,
        })`

Answer (score 0):

I think your request already has the cookies unrolled in the header instead of in a cookies object.  So extracting it from there should be workable. Its probable that your req was a previous-request-rebuild - wherein it just was copying headers instead of creating the cookie object?  This code should give you the idea.

```
const apolloClient = (req) => {
  const authLink = setContext(_ => {
    const cookieToken = req.getHeader('Cookie')
        .map(ck => /^([^=]+)=(.+)/.exec(ck))
        .filter(([_, key]) => key == "token")
        .map(([_, _, cooked]) => cooked)

    return {
      headers: {
        ...req.headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${req.cookies.token || cookieToken.shift()}`,
      },
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually do have access to my `token` but it just not showing in the request headers oddly

Comment: you have ApolloLink.from([ onError(...), authLink.concat(createhttplink(...))]

It occurs to me to wonder if

ApolloLink.from([onError(...), authLink, createHttpLink(...)]) might not put them together equivalently?

Answer (score 0):

So I was looking at [this](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/blob/480df382cf7db486ae76c56ac2522134d77e36fa/packages/apollo-link-http/README.md) and noticing their middleware used a different phrasing, maybe its just more explicit, but... I'd explore this...

```
const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  operation.setContext({
     headers: {
       ...headers,
       authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
     }});
  return forward(operation);
});
```